# Найти максимальный элемент списка

Tags: java

В списке лежат объекты класса, у которого 2 поля. Хочу найти элемент списка, у которого наибольшее значение 2-го поля (оно типа double). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5):

[Collections.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь переменную в которую будешь сохранять элемент который имеет наибольшее значение.
Object[] frame;
теперь в цикле тебе необходимо перебрать все элементы

```
ArrayList<Object[]> arr();
fram = arr.get(0);

for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
       /*в данном цикле нужно сравнивать каждый элемент (arr.get(i)[1]) с frame[1]. Если frame больше переходишь к следующему элементу. Если frame меньше, в frame записываешь arr.get(i) - таким образом у тебя в frame будет всегда элемент где значение максимальное*/
    if (arr.get(i)[1]>frame[1]) {
        frame = arr.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пузырек долгий метод.. нужен по-быстрее..

Comment: Долгий относительно чего. На списке в несколько тысяч записей не заметите разницу.

Comment: a_gura - спс за ссылку, у списков есть много готовых методов.

Comment: @Stas0n пузырек - это метод сортировки. Код же выше представляет собой просто проход по списку и к пузырьку не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: это наверное такая ассоциация была )

Comment: @Stas0n, а как Вы представляете *"магию"* поиска максимума, без просмотра (по одному разу) всех элементов?

Поделитесь фантазиями.

--

@G1yyK, после 

    frame = arr.get(0) 

цикл for можно делать от 1. А если размер arr не меняется (как в этом случае), то лучше не лениться и не надеяться на оптимизатор, а ручками вытащить инвариант (arr.size()) из цикла.

`frame[1]` будем считать *опиской*.

Comment: Да про цикл правильно подметил, чет сразу не сообразил, так будет чуточку быстрее.

frame[1] не описка. Object[] frame = new Object(тут любое значение,new Double)
и сравнивать будем соответственно по второму значению.

Comment: @avp ну в случае упорядоченных списков...